# How can I redirect port in android?

Tags: android, port

I want to redirect the all the port to the specified port in android. In Ubuntu or raspberry, I can use

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000

sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-port 20000 -m owner ! --uid-owner root
```

How can I redirect the port like the above commands in android? Do I need a rooted device?

Comment: `sudo` commands in general require a rooted device. But I don't know if there's any other way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

We can root the device and download Termux to run the commands same as ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You should try PORT FORWARDER apps from google play. There are many port forwarders Available there.
Anyone of those can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is use `adb` for this:

```
$ adb reverse tcp:8888 tcp:9999
```

For infos see

```
$ adb --help
[...]
  reverse --list           list all reverse socket connections from device
  reverse [--no-rebind] REMOTE LOCAL
     reverse socket connection using:
       tcp:<port> (<remote> may be "tcp:0" to pick any open port)
       localabstract:<unix domain socket name>
       localreserved:<unix domain socket name>
       localfilesystem:<unix domain socket name>
  reverse --remove REMOTE  remove specific reverse socket connection
  reverse --remove-all     remove all reverse socket connections from device
```